# Firestore Trouble with get() then add()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

New to Vue.js and Firestore, struggling to do something I feel should be simple.

1) I query an existing template doc in my firestore to retrieve some default values.

2) I want to create a new record in different collection using these default values.

I can console log the default values from the template and they show correctly (in the code below, the "console.log" shows the values presently in the template document, so I believe the variables beginning with "this." should now have my correct values, ready to use in creating a new document, yes?

But when running the subsequent .add() using these default values, the new document is created in 'nodes', but values are NOT the values retrieved in the first query, the values are instead what I initially initialized the variables to when creating them in data(), in this case, blank strings. The newly created doc in 'nodes' collection has the correct fields, but they are blank strings just showing "" with no value.

This function createNewLocation() is kicked off by a button press on the page if that matters. It seems to work, I just can't get the values to copy over.

I have tried this a few different ways. No matter what I do, I can't make the returned values from the query useful in the rest of my code. Does this have something to do with latency where the first query hasn't returned when the new doc is created? If so how to get around this?

Thank you.

```js
<script>
import db from '../components/firebaseInit'
export default {
    name: 'loc-new',
    data () {
        return {
            //Values from entry form
            new_loc_id: null,
            new_loc_name: null,

            //Holders for default values used in location creation
            node_hw_ver: 0,
            node_sw_ver: 0,
            node_user_descr: '',
            node_user_name: '',
            node_type_class: '',
            node_type_id: 0,

        }
    },
    methods: {
        createNewLocation () { 
            //get template /templates/(nodes)/node_templates/
            db.collection('templates').doc('nodes').collection('node_templates')
                .where('use_for_new', '==', true).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    this.node_hw_ver = doc.data().default_hw_ver
                    console.log("hw ", this.node_hw_ver)
                    this.node_sw_ver = doc.data().default_sw_ver
                    console.log("sw ", this.node_sw_ver)
                    this.node_user_descr = doc.data().default_user_descr
                    console.log("descr ", this.node_user_descr)
                    this.node_user_name = doc.data().default_user_name
                    console.log("name ", this.node_user_name)
                    this.node_type_class = doc.data().type_class
                    console.log("class ", this.node_type_class)
                    this.node_type_id = doc.data().type_id
                    console.log("id ", this.node_type_id)
                })
            })
            db.collection('nodes').add({
                    loc_id: this.new_loc_id,
                    addr: 1,
                    user_name: this.node_user_name,
                    user_descr: this.node_user_descr,
                    type_id: this.node_type_id,
                    type_class: this.node_type_class
            })
            .then(function(docRef){
                //do nothing                
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error("Error adding node document: ", error)
                return null
            })

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you mean to add the document **inside** the callback of the query, rather than immediately after the query is executed, but before it's finished?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I think I need to add it in a callback but I don't understand how to actually write the syntax for that. I've read about callbacks but I haven't been able to make sense of it. I don't really understand the arrow function and all the curly brackets, etc. Logically I understand what I'm trying to do, just not sure how to actually write the syntax. I normally write in C for low level microprocessors, this is my first attempt at js for a web app. I'm really struggling with the promises. I just want the data, don't really care how I get it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it working. I understand it was not updating because the promise had not yet returned. I'm a bit fuzzy on syntax of js (I normally work in C), so this was just trial and error and may not be clean or correct, but this does work if anyone else stumbles on this post.

I have added the .add() query inside the .then of the first query. I understand this can be done using 'await' but I couldn't understand the syntax in the various examples I found. There may be a cleaner way to do this, but it works for now.

```
<script>
import db from '../components/firebaseInit'
export default {
    name: 'loc-new',
    data () {
        return {
            //Values from entry form
            new_loc_id: null,
            new_loc_name: null,

            //Holders for default values used in location creation
            node_hw_ver: 0,
            node_sw_ver: 0,
            node_user_descr: '',
            node_user_name: '',
            node_type_class: '',
            node_type_id: 0

        }
    },
    methods: {
        createNewLocation () { 

            //get template /templates/(nodes)/node_templates/
            db.collection('templates').doc('nodes').collection('node_templates')
                .where('use_for_new', '==', true).limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                    this.node_hw_ver = doc.data().default_hw_ver
                    console.log("hw ", this.node_hw_ver)
                    this.node_sw_ver = doc.data().default_sw_ver
                    console.log("sw ", this.node_sw_ver)
                    this.node_user_descr = doc.data().default_user_descr
                    console.log("descr ", this.node_user_descr)
                    this.node_user_name = doc.data().default_user_name
                    console.log("name ", this.node_user_name)
                    this.node_type_class = doc.data().type_class
                    console.log("class ", this.node_type_class)
                    this.node_type_id = doc.data().type_id
                    console.log("id ", this.node_type_id)

                    db.collection('nodes').add({
                    loc_id: this.new_loc_id,
                    addr: 1,
                    user_name: this.node_user_name,
                    user_descr: this.node_user_descr,
                    type_id: this.node_type_id,
                    type_class: this.node_type_class
                        })
                        .then(function(docRef){
                            //do nothing                
                        })
                        .catch(function(error){
                            console.error("Error adding node document: ", error)
                            return null
                        })
                })

        })
    }
}
</script>
```